# Isar DB based flutter app fails to build on android device/emulator

Tags: flutter, flutter-isar

#### Dart SDK

environment:
sdk: '>=2.19.1 <3.0.0'

#### Isar version

isar: ^3.0.5
isar_flutter_libs: ^3.0.5

#### Terminal output

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':isar_flutter_libs:parseDebugLocalResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':isar_flutter_libs:androidApis'.
> Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-30\android.jar.
> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-30\android.jar

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: try `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Didn't Work

Comment: Can you share your main.dart File?

Comment: have you been able to solve this issue on your side?

Answer (score 1):

- flutter clean
- flutter pub get

1. Open AVD Manager
2. Wipe Data (delete datas from emulator)
3. Open emulator
4. Try to run app

Please at next time provide

- flutter Doctor
- main.dart file

Answer (score 0):

Isar does not support x86 devices